# Unable to delete Excel Chart Labels

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I am trying to delete all data labels in an Excel chart for each of the series but somehow my code doesn't delete any of the data labels on the chart. Please let me know if there is something lacking in my code below.  I am currently using Microsoft Office 365 and the file is an xlsb .

Thanks in advance and really appreciate your help.

```
Sub DeleteDataLabels()
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Call UnprotectSheet
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate


SeriesCount = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
MsgBox SeriesCount

' To delete the code
For i = 1 To SeriesCount
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).HasDataLabels Then
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).DataLabels.Select
            Selection.Delete
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to [avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code. And you want to use `.FullSeriesCollection(i).Delete`

Comment: Thanks @cybernetice.nomad but I amended it to 'If ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).HasDataLabels Then ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Delete End If'                                         (and it still doesn't work)

Comment: If you step thru the code, does it enter the `If` block?

Comment: @Kubie, yes it appears to .

Comment: Yes  @Kubie, it does. (used a message box).

Comment: Why not just do the whole chart: `activechart.applydatalabels xlDataLabelsShowNone`

Comment: Thanks @Rory. It worked!

Comment: @Rory would you like to post it as a solution or should I go ahead and do it? Thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: Also thanks @Kubie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Rory's comment. Replace the if statement with the line of code below the comment.

```
 Sub DeleteDataLabels()

 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
 Call UnprotectSheet
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate


 SeriesCount = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
 MsgBox SeriesCount

 'Replace the if statement with this line of code
 ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowNone
 End Sub
```